# For alphanumeric tags separated by commas?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to RegEx and JavaScript and I was wondering if anyone knew what the RegEx would be for detecting whether or not an input field contained the following type of format:

- At least one alphanumeric tag which can contain spaces (e.g. "Test Tag" but not "Test@Tag")
- Each tag separated by a single comma and nothing else, no spaces. (e.g. "Cars,Vehicle,Tiger Cactus, Bed")

An example of what I mean is this, these would be **valid** tags:

```
boy,man,girl,woman,tyrannosaurus rex,lion
```

And these would be **invalid** tags:

```
hat, cat, rat, c3po, @gmail
```

Because there are spaces between the tags and invalid characters.

Also, how would I count the tags for imposing a limit?

**Edited for clarification!**

Comment: Are the quotes part of the string? What characters are allowed in tags? Are empty/whitespace only tags allowed?

Comment: Sorry, I have now edited the OP to be more precise.

Comment: "alphanumeric" usually doesn't include spaces, but your example contains "Long Tag" which contains a space.

Comment: Well, alphanumeric characters with spaces only allowed in the actual tags and not between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?:([\w\s]+)(?:,\s*))*` would get any number of tags separated by commas.

`(?:([\w\s]+)(?:,\s*)){n}` would match n tags where n is an integer.

`(?:([\w\s]+)(?:,\s*)){0,n}` would match 0 to n tags where n is an integer.

In order to count the tags, you'll need to check the number of captured groups.

Comment: If you don't want spaces between the tags, then you can change "(?:,\s*)" to "," which should make your regex more readable...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your regex using the example I gave above and I couldn't get it to validate it.

Comment: The way I posted won't include the last tag in a list (it is matching a tag followed by a comma).  To include the last tag, use something like this:
(?:([\w\s]+),)*([\w\s]+)

Comment: I realise my wording was causing some major confusion, I've reworded the whole original post in the hopes of finding an answer. Thanks for your time.